# How can I improve this JavaScript DOM-manipulation data-structure/algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

**Goal**

I've got a DOM with about 70 elements on it (divs with some content) . I need to move and toggle the display of those divs quite a lot and also quite fast. The speed is one of the most important things. The trigger for moving and toggling these divs is a search query, kind of like [Google Instant](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/instant-about.html), except that all the DOM elements I move around and toggle are loaded the first time (so no more calls to the server).

**Implementation**

I've implemented this in the following way: alongside the DOM I pass in a JavaScript array of objects representing the divs along with their attributes like position, contents etcetera. This array acts like a mirror to the DOM. When the user starts typing I start looping through the array and calculating, per div/object, what needs to be done to it. I actually loop over this array a couple of times: I first check if I need to look at a div/object, then I look at the object, then whether I need to look at the contents, then I look at the contents.

One of the things I do in these loops is the setting of flags for DOM-manipulation. As I understand it, reading and manipulating and the DOM is one of the slower operations in JavaScript, as compared to the other stuff I'm doing (looping, reading and writing object attributes etc.). I also did some profiling, confirming this assumption. So at every corner I've tried to prevent "touching" the DOM to increase performance. At the end of my algorithm I loop once more, execute all the necessary DOM actions and reset the flags to signal they've been read. For cross-browser compatibility I use jQuery to actually do the DOM actions (selecting, moving, toggling). I do *not* use jQuery to loop over my array.

**Problem**

My problem now is that I *think* my code and data structure is a bit ugly. I have this rather 
large multidimensional array with lots of attributes and flags. I repeatedly loop over it with functions calling functions calling functions. When running into problems I can (still) somewhat easily debug stuff, but it doesn't *feel* right.

**Question**

Is there a design pattern or common solution to this kind of problem? I suspect I could implement some sort of smart coupling between the array and the DOM where I would not have to explicitly set flags and execute DOM actions, but I've no idea how such a coupling should work or if it's even a good idea or just complicating things.

Are there any other data-structure or algorithmic principles I've overlooked when solving this problem?

Thanks!

**Update**
As requested I've added my code, it's about 700 lines. Note: I'm not polluting the global namespace, these functions are defined and used inside a closure.

```
/**
 * Applies the filter (defined by the currentQuery and to the cats array)
 *
 * -checks whether matching is needed
 * -if needed does the matching
 * -checks whether DOM action is needed
 * -if needed executes DOM action
 *
 * cats is an array of objects representing categories
 * which themselves contain an array of objects representing links
 * with some attributes
 *
 * cats = (array) array of categories through which to search
 * currentQuery = (string) with which to find matches within the cats
 * previousQuery = (string) with previously-typed-in query
 *
 * no return values, results in DOM action and manipulation of cats array
 */
function applyFilter(cats,currentQuery, previousQuery) {
    cats = flagIfMatchingIsNeededForCats(cats,currentQuery,previousQuery);
    cats = matchCats(cats,currentQuery);
    cats = flagIfMatchingIsNeededForLinks(cats,currentQuery,previousQuery);
    cats = matchLinks(cats,currentQuery);
    cats = flagIfDisplayToggleNeeded(cats);
    if ( currentQuery.length > 0 ) {
        cats = flagIfMoveNeeded(cats);
    } else {
        // move everything back to its original position
        cats = flagMoveToOriginalPosition(cats);
    }

    // take action on the items that need a DOM action
    cats = executeDomActions(cats);
}

/**
* Sets a flag on a category if it needs matching, parses and returns cats
*
* Loops through all categories and sets a boolean to signal whether they 
* need matching.
*
* cats = (array) an array with all the category-objects in it
* currentQuery = (string) the currently typed-in query
* previousQuery = (string) the query that was previously typed in
*
* returns (array) cats, possibly in a different state
*/ 
function flagIfMatchingIsNeededForCats(cats,currentQuery,previousQuery) {
    var newQueryIsLonger = isNewQueryLonger(currentQuery, previousQuery);

    // check if matching is necessary for categories
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        cats[i].matchingNeeded = isMatchingNeededForCat(
            cats[i].matches
            ,newQueryIsLonger
            ,currentQuery.length
            ,cats[i].noMatchFoundAtNumChars
        );
    }
    return cats;
}

/**
* Whether the new query is longer than the previous one
*
* currentQuery = (string) the currently typed-in query
* previousQuery = (string) the query that was previously typed in
*
* returns (boolean) true/false
*/
function isNewQueryLonger(currentQuery, previousQuery) {
    if (previousQuery == false) {
        return true;
    }

    return currentQuery.length > previousQuery.length
}

/**
* Deduces if a category needs to be matched to the current query
*
* This function helps in improving performance. Matching is done using 
* indexOf() which isn't slow of itself but preventing even fast processes
* is a good thing (most of the time). The function looks at the category,
* the current and previous query, then decides whether
* matching is needed.
*
* currentlyMatched = (boolean) on whether the boolean was matched to the previous query
* newQueryIsLonger = (boolean) whether the new query is longer
* queryLength = (int) the length of the current query
* noMatchFoundAtNumChars = (int) this variable gets set (to an int) for a 
*   category when it switches from being matched to being not-matched. The
*   number indicates the number of characters in the first query that did
*   not match the category. This helps in performance because we don't need
*   to recheck the categoryname if it doesn't match now and the new query is
*   even longer.
*
* returns (boolean) true/false
*/
function isMatchingNeededForCat(currentlyMatched, newQueryIsLonger ,queryLength ,noMatchFoundAtNumChars) {
    if (typeof(currentlyMatched) == 'undefined') {
        // this happens the first time we look at a category, for all 
        // categories this happens with an empty query and that matches with
        // everything
        currentlyMatched = true;
    }

    if (currentlyMatched && newQueryIsLonger) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!currentlyMatched && !newQueryIsLonger) {
        // if currentlyMatched == false, we always have a value for
        // noMatchFoundAtNumChars

        // matching is needed if the first "no-match" state was found 
        // at a number of characters equal to or bigger than 
        // queryLength
        if ( queryLength < noMatchFoundAtNumChars ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
* Does matching on categories for all categories that need it.
*
* Sets noMatchFoundAtNumChars to a number if the category does not match.
* Sets noMatchFoundAtNumChars to false if the category matches once again.
*
* cats = (array) an array with all the category-objects in it
* currentQuery = (string) the currently typed-in query
*
* returns (array) cats, possibly in a different state
*/
function matchCats(cats,currentQuery) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        if (cats[i].matchingNeeded) {
            cats[i].matches = categoryMatches(cats[i],currentQuery);

            // set noMatchFoundAtNumChars
            if (cats[i].matches) {
                cats[i].noMatchFoundAtNumChars = false;
            } else {
                cats[i].noMatchFoundAtNumChars = currentQuery.length;
            }
        }
    }
    return cats;
}

/**
* Check if the category name matches the query
*
* A simple indexOf call to the string category_name
*
* category = (object) a category object
* query = (string) the query
*
* return (boolean) true/false
*/
function categoryMatches(category,query) {
    catName = category.category_name.toLowerCase();
    if (catName.indexOf(query) !== -1 ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
* Checks links to see whether they need matching
*
* Loops through all cats, selects the non-matching, for every link decides
* whether it needs matching
*
* cats = (array) an array with all the category-objects in it
* currentQuery = the currently typed-in query
* previousQuery = the query that was previously typed in
*
* returns (array) cats, possibly in a different state
*/
function flagIfMatchingIsNeededForLinks(cats,currentQuery,previousQuery) {
    var newQueryIsLonger = isNewQueryLonger(currentQuery, previousQuery);
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        if (!cats[i].matches) { // only necessary when cat does not match
            for (var k = 0; k < cats[i].links.length; k++) {
                cats[i].links[k].matchingNeeded = isMatchingNeededForLink(
                    cats[i].links[k].matches
                    ,newQueryIsLonger
                    ,currentQuery.length
                    ,cats[i].links[k].noMatchFoundAtNumChars
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return cats;
}

/**
* Checks whether matching is needed for a specific link
*
* This function helps in improving performance. Matching is done using 
* indexOf() for every (relevant) link property, this function helps decide
* whether that *needs* to be done. The function looks at some link 
* properties, the current and previous query, then decides whether
* matching is needed for the link.
*
* currentlyMatched = (boolean) on whether the boolean was matched to the previous query
* newQueryIsLonger = (boolean) whether the new query is longer
* queryLength = (int) the length of the current query
* noMatchFoundAtNumChars = (int) this variable gets set (to an int) for a 
*   link when it switches from being matched to being not-matched. The
*   number indicates the number of characters in the first query that did
*   not match the link. This helps in performance because we don't need
*   to recheck the link properties in certain circumstances.
*
* return (boolean) true/false
*/
function isMatchingNeededForLink(currentlyMatched, newQueryIsLonger ,queryLength ,noMatchFoundAtNumChars) {
    if (typeof(currentlyMatched) == 'undefined') {
        // this happens to a link the first time a cat does not match and
        // we want to scan the links for matching
        return true;            
    }

    if (currentlyMatched && newQueryIsLonger) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!currentlyMatched && !newQueryIsLonger) {
        // if currentlyMatched == false, we always have a value for
        // noMatchFoundAtNumChars

        // matching is needed if the first "no-match" state was found 
        // at a number of characters equal to or bigger than 
        // queryLength
        if ( queryLength < noMatchFoundAtNumChars ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
* Does matching on links for all links that need it.
*
* Sets noMatchFoundAtNumChars to a number if the link does not match.
* Sets noMatchFoundAtNumChars to false if the link matches once again.
*
* cats = (array) an array with all the category-objects in it
* currentQuery = (string) the currently typed-in query
*
* returns (array) cats, possibly in a different state
*/
function matchLinks(cats,currentQuery) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        // category does not match, check if links in the category match
        if (!cats[i].matches) {
            for (var k = 0; k < cats[i].links.length; k++) {
                if (cats[i].links[k].matchingNeeded) {
                    cats[i].links[k].matches = linkMatches(cats[i].links[k],currentQuery);
                }

                // set noMatchFoundAtNumChars
                if (cats[i].links[k].matches) {
                    cats[i].links[k].noMatchFoundAtNumChars = false;
                } else {
                    cats[i].links[k].noMatchFoundAtNumChars = currentQuery.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cats;
}    

/**
* Check if any of the link attributes match the query
*
* Loops through all link properties, skips the irrelevant ones we use for filtering
*
* category = (object) a category object
* query = (string) the query
*
* return (boolean) true/false
*/
function linkMatches(link,query) {
    for (var property in link) {
        // just try to match certain properties
        if (
                !( // if it's *not* one of the following
                    property == 'title'
                    || property == 'label'
                    || property == 'url'
                    || property == 'keywords'
                    || property == 'col'
                    || property == 'row'
                )
        ){
            continue;
        }

        // if it's an empty string there's no match
        if( !link[property] ) {
            continue;
        }

        var linkProperty = link[property].toLowerCase();
        if (linkProperty.indexOf(query) !== -1){
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

/**
* Flags if toggling of display is needed for a category.
*
* Loops through all categories. If a category needs some DOM
* action (hiding/showing) it is flagged for action. This helps in 
* performance because we prevent unnecessary calls to the DOM (which are 
* slow).
*
* cats = (array) an array with all the category-objects in it
*
* returns (array) cats, possibly in a different state
*/
function flagIfDisplayToggleNeeded(cats) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        // this happens the first time we look at a category
        if (typeof(cats[i].currentlyDisplayed) == 'undefined') {
            cats[i].currentlyDisplayed = true;
        }

        var visibleLinks = 0;
        // a cat that matches, all links need to be shown
        if (cats[i].matches) {
            visibleLinks = cats[i].links.length;
        } else {
            // a cat that does not match
            for (var k = 0; k < cats[i].links.length; k++) {
                if (cats[i].links[k].matches) {
                    visibleLinks++;
                }
            }            
        }

        // hide/show categories if they have any visible links
        if (!cats[i].currentlyDisplayed && visibleLinks > 0 ) {
            cats[i].domActionNeeded = 'show';
        } else if( cats[i].currentlyDisplayed && visibleLinks == 0 ){
            cats[i].domActionNeeded = 'hide';
        }           
    }
    return cats;
}

/**
* Flags categories to be moved to other position.
*
* Loops through all categories and looks if they are distributed properly. 
* If not it moves them to another position. It remembers the old position so
* it can get the categories back in their original position.
*
* cats = (array) an array with all the category-objects in it
*
* returns (array) cats, possibly in a different state
*/
function flagIfMoveNeeded(cats) {
    var numCats, numColumns, displayedCats, i, moveToColumn, tmp;

    numColumns = getNumColumns(cats);
    numDisplayedCats = getNumDisplayedCats(cats);        
    columnDistribution = divideInPiles(numDisplayedCats, numColumns);

    // optional performance gain: only move stuff when necessary
    // think about this some more

    // we convert the distribution in columns to a table so we get columns
    // and positions
    catDistributionTable = convertColumnToTableDistribution(columnDistribution);

    // sort the categories, highest positions first
    // catPositionComparison is a function to do the sorting with
    // we could improve performance by doing this only once
    cats = cats.sort(catPositionComparison);

    for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i += 1) {
        if( categoryWillBeDisplayed(cats[i]) ){
            tmp = getNewPosition(catDistributionTable); // returns multiple variables
            catDistributionTable = tmp.catDistributionTable;
            cats[i].moveToColumn = tmp.moveToColumn;
            cats[i].moveToPosition = tmp.moveToPosition;
        } else {
            cats[i].moveToColumn = false;
            cats[i].moveToPosition = false;
        }
    }
    return cats;
}

/**
* A comparison function to help the sorting in flagIfMoveNeeded()
*
* This function compares two categories and returns an integer value 
* enabling the sort function to work.
*
* cat1 = (obj) a category
* cat2 = (obj) another category
*
* returns (int) signaling which category should come before the other
*/
function catPositionComparison(cat1, cat2) {
    if (cat1.category_position > cat2.category_position) {
        return 1; // cat1 > cat2
    } else if (cat1.category_position < cat2.category_position) {
        return -1; // cat1 < cat2
    }

    // the positions are equal, so now compare on column, if we need the 
    // performance we could skip this
    if (cat1.category_column > cat2.category_column) {
        return 1; // cat1 > cat2
    } else if (cat1.category_column < cat2.category_column) {
        return -1; // cat1 < cat2
    }

    return 0; // position and column are equal
}

/**
* Checks if a category will be displayed for the currentQuery
*
* cat = category (object) 
*
* returns (boolean) true/false
*/
function categoryWillBeDisplayed(cat) {
    if( (cat.currentlyDisplayed === true  && cat.domActionNeeded !== 'hide')
        ||
        (cat.currentlyDisplayed === false && cat.domActionNeeded === 'show')
    ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Gets the number of unique columns in all categories
 *
 * Loops through all cats and saves the columnnumbers as keys, insuring
 * uniqueness. Returns the number of
 *
 * cats = (array) of category objects
 *
 * returns (int) number of unique columns of all categories
 */
function getNumColumns(cats) {
    var columnNumber, uniqueColumns, numUniqueColumns, i;

    uniqueColumns = [];
    for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i += 1) {
        columnNumber = cats[i].category_column;
        uniqueColumns[columnNumber] = true;
    }

    numUniqueColumns = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < uniqueColumns.length; i += 1) {
        if( uniqueColumns[i] === true ){
            numUniqueColumns += 1
        }
    }
    return numUniqueColumns;
}

/**
 * Gets the number of categories that will be displayed for the current query
 *
 * cats = (array) of category objects
 *
 * returns (int) number of categories that will be displayed
 */
function getNumDisplayedCats(cats) {
    var numDisplayedCats, i;

    numDisplayedCats = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i += 1) {
        if( categoryWillBeDisplayed(cats[i]) ){
            numDisplayedCats += 1;
        }
    }
    return numDisplayedCats;
}

/**
 * Evenly divides a number of items into piles
 *
 * Uses a recursive algorithm to divide x items as evenly as possible over
 * y piles.
 *
 * items = (int) a number of items to be divided
 * piles = (int) the number of piles to divide items into
 *
 * return an array with numbers representing the number of items in each pile
 */
function divideInPiles(items, piles) {
    var averagePerPileRoundedUp, rest, pilesDivided;
    pilesDivided = [];

    if (piles === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    averagePerPileRoundedUp = Math.ceil(items / piles);
    pilesDivided.push(averagePerPileRoundedUp);
    rest = items - averagePerPileRoundedUp;

    if (piles > 1) {
        pilesDivided = pilesDivided.concat(divideInPiles(rest, piles - 1)); // recursion
    }

    return pilesDivided;
}

/**
 * Converts a column distribution to a table
 *
 * Receives a one-dimensional distribution array and converts it to a two-
 * dimensional distribution array.
 *
 * columnDist (array) an array of ints, example [3,3,2]
 *
 * returns (array) two dimensional array, rows with "cells"
 * example: [[true,true,true],[true,true,true],[true,true,false]]
 * returns false on failure
 */
function convertColumnToTableDistribution(columnDist) {
    'use strict';
    var numRows, row, numCols, col, tableDist;

    if (columnDist[0] === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    // the greatest number of items are always in the first column
    numRows = columnDist[0];
    numCols = columnDist.length;
    tableDist = []; // we 

    for (row = 0; row < numRows; row += 1) {
        tableDist.push([]); // add a row
        // add "cells"
        for (col = 0; col < numCols; col += 1) {
            if (columnDist[col] > 0) {
                // the column still contains items
                tableDist[row].push(true);
                columnDist[col] -= 1;
            } else {
                tableDist[row][col] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return tableDist;
}

/**
* Returns the next column and position to place a category in.
*
* Loops through the table to find the first position that can be used. Rows
* and positions have indexes that start at zero, we add 1 in the return 
* object.
*
* catDistributionTable = (array) of rows, with positions in them
*
* returns (object) with the mutated catDistributionTable, a column and a 
* position
*/
function getNewPosition(catDistributionTable) {
    var numRows, row, col, numCols, moveToColumn, moveToPosition;

    numRows = catDistributionTable.length;

    findposition:
    for (row = 0; row < numRows; row += 1) {
        numCols = catDistributionTable[row].length;
        for ( col = 0; col < numCols; col += 1) {
            if (catDistributionTable[row][col] === true) {
                moveToColumn = col;
                moveToPosition = row;
                catDistributionTable[row][col] = false;
                break findposition;
            }
        }
    }

    // zero-indexed to how it is in the DOM, starting with 1
    moveToColumn += 1;
    moveToPosition += 1;

    return {
        'catDistributionTable'  : catDistributionTable
        ,'moveToColumn'         : moveToColumn
        ,'moveToPosition'       : moveToPosition
    };
}

/**
* Sets the target position of a category to its original location
*
* Each category in the DOM has attributes defining their original position.
* After moving them around we might want to move them back to their original
* position, this function flags all categories to do just that.
*
* cats = (array) of category objects
*
* All of the possible return values
*/
function flagMoveToOriginalPosition(cats) {
    for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i += 1) {
        cats[i].moveToColumn = cats.category_column;
        cats[i].moveToPosition = cats.category_position;
    }
    return cats;
}

/**
* Execute DOM actions for the items that need DOM actions
*
* Parses all categories, executes DOM actions on the categories that
* require a DOM action.
*
* cats = (array) an array with all the category-objects in it
*
* no return values
*/
function executeDomActions(cats) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        var category_id = cats[i].category_id;

        // toggle display of columns
        if (cats[i].domActionNeeded == 'show') {
            showCategory(category_id);
            cats[i].currentlyDisplayed = true;
        }

        if (cats[i].domActionNeeded == 'hide') {
            hideCategory(category_id);
            cats[i].currentlyDisplayed = false;

        }
        cats[i].domActionNeeded = false;

        // for every currentlyDisplayed category move it to new location
        // if necessary
        if (cats[i].currentlyDisplayed && cats[i].moveToColumn !== false) {
            cats[i] = moveCat(cats[i]);
        }
    }
    return cats;
}

/**
* Show a certain category
*
* category_id = (int) the id of the category that needs to be shown
*
* no return values
*/
function showCategory(category_id) {
    $('#' + category_id).show();
}

/**
* Hide a certain category
*
* category_id = (int) the id of the category that needs to be hidden
*
* no return values
*/
function hideCategory(category_id) {
    $('#' + category_id).hide();
}

/**
 * Moves a category to the position set in its attributes
 *
 * A category can have attributes defining the column and position (or row)
 * this function moves the category to the correct column and position.
 *
 * cat = (object) category
 *
 * returns (object) category
 */
function moveCat(cat) {
    var columnSelector, catSelector;
    columnSelector = '#column' + cat.moveToColumn + ' .column_inner' + ' .hiddenblocks';
    catSelector = '#' + cat.category_id;
    $(columnSelector).prepend($(catSelector));

    // reset target coordinates
    cat.moveToColumn = false;
    cat.moveToPosition = false;

    return cat;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd have to show your code to get better ideas.  We need to see what's ugly about it, what you're doing and then develop ideas for a better approach.  Not much we can suggest with such little specific information.

Comment: Please post some code.  This question is extremely vague without it.  You may also want to post it on [codereview.SE] instead.

Comment: I can see how my question can be seen more concrete (and that's why I posted it). I do however think that thinking about datastructures/algorithms can be done without having concrete examples. #offtopic

Answer (score 2):

Well commented and formatted JavaScript, kudos sir!

First off, it seams like your use-case would be perfect for a SQL database query. Sending your query to a DB and getting the category IDs and locations back would be much simpler than your current implementation. I assume you do it all client side because you don't have access to a DB, your data is fairly static, or you're not confident in the real-time speed of your database.

To speed up your current implementation lower case and concatenate all your Link data properties into one property before hand.

```
function linkMatches(link,query) {
    if (link["ConcatenatedLCasedProperties"].indexOf(query) !== -1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*EDIT* Here's a faster/more efficient version of your divideInPiles function.

```
function divideInPiles(items, piles) {
    var result = [];
    var perPile = Math.floor(items/piles);
    var leftOver = items % piles;
    if(piles == 0) 
        return false;
    for(var x=0; x<piles; x++) 
        result.push(perPile + (--leftOver >= 0 ? 1: 0));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The matching algorithms would indeed be better suited for SQL, however I need this 
functionality to work as fast as possible, so doing a server request per 
character typed is unnecessarily slow. I'm lucky to have all of the data I'm querying
available on the client-side when the page is loaded.

Good tip on the link properties, thanks, I will look into that. 

And thanks for the kudos, I do my best :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it really possible to use tree structure there. Also you can try to implement manipulate some graph algorithms. Also, think it could be reasonable to have some hidden div on each level of the tree, when you store most popular information, and you can just display it if necessary instead of manipulation with div content.

But, think that it needs to specify you task with more details. Some real cases could be really helpfull.

Comment: A tree structure would not be a good fit here because I don't have nodes being parents of the same types of nodes. And graph-algorithm, what are you suggesting exactly? Having a "data"-store at every DOM-element would only slow down my algorithm versus having a centralized data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Since DOM-Operations are costly, you should aim to detach the elements from the tree, work on them and then re-attach them to the DOM. This is easily done with JQuery's .detach().

I do not know your data structure, but the fastest loops are plain loops with counters. Remember to store any possible length values in a variable, to not lookup the length in every loop.

Comment: Good tip on the .length computation! I save my DOM actions for the last moment so I think that's fairly optimal.